# Hilbert function of (weighted) projectivized tangent cones

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given an algebraic variety $X$ and a point $P$ on $X$, the tangent cone at $X$ is defined to be
$$\displaystyle \text{Spec}\left(\bigoplus_{i \geq 0} \mathfrak{m}^i / \mathfrak{m}^{i+1} \right)$$ 
where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal of the local ring of $X$ at $P$. Similarly, we may define the projectivised tangent cone to be
$$\displaystyle \text{Proj} \left(\bigoplus_{i \geq 0} \mathfrak{m}^i / \mathfrak{m}^{i+1} \right).$$
My question concerns the Hilbert function $H(s)$ of this algebraic set. In particular, does it agree with a polynomial for sufficiently large $s$, and does it satisfy
$$\displaystyle H(s) = \frac{\mu s^{r-1}}{(r-1)!} + O(r^{r-2}),$$
where $r$ is the dimension of $X$ and $\mu$ the multiplicity of the point $P$? If so, why is this the case?

My next question concerns the seemingly plausible concept of weighted projective tangent cones, which would be tangent cones in weighted projective space, say $\mathbb{P}(a_0, \cdots, a_n)$ for some positive integral weights $a_0, \cdots, a_n$. It seems that the only modification needed to be made in the proj construction is to take weighted projective ideals that do not contain the irrelevant ideal. In this case, I expect the weights to appear in the asymptotic for the Hilbert function, namely I expect
$$\displaystyle H(s) = \frac{\mu s^{r-1}}{a_0 \cdots a_n (r-1)!} + O(r^{r-2}).$$
However, I have not found this in the literature anywhere. Any references or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes; this is just saying that the degree and dimension of the tangent cone is $\mu$ and $r-1$, respectively, which can be found in many books, e.g. Harris' "First Course" book.  For your second question, I don't know what you would mean by a "weighted projective tangent cone."  The ring $\oplus m^i/m^{i+1}$ is canonically $\mathbb{Z}$-graded.

Comment: I merely want a 'tangent cone' for a point on a subvariety of say, $\mathbb{P}(a_0, \cdots, a_n)$. Is such a set a projective variety, regardless of the space it lives in?

Comment: The tangent cone is a local intrinsic construction of an abstract variety, and doesn't "see" any embedding into another space. Subvarieties of weighted projective spaces still have projectivized tangent cones, which are subschemes of the projectivized Zariski tangent space (which is an ordinary projective space). 

Comment: You can indeed weigh differently different variables locally, and get a tangent cone which lives in $\mathbb{P}(a_0,\dots,a_n)$. Whether this is useful or not will depend on the local nature of the singular variety, and not on whether it is globally embedded in some weighted projective space. Consider the tangent cone at the origin of the affine plane curve given by $F=(y^2-x^3)(y^2+x^3)+x^5+y^5$, with weights (2,3). It has two components, corresponding to the two branches of F=0. But if you do that to an ordinary singularity, you see nothing.